# Recover code deleted by Visual C# Form Designer?

Tags: c#, version-control, windows-forms-designer

So, I made a program in Visual C# 2010 Express. Finished enough to work, and pretty darned good for my first attempt at the language. But then I foolishly decided, "Hey, this program needs a close confirmation dialog before I send it out!" So I write the function, and then I go into the auto-generated code to bind said function appropriately.

**KABOOM!**

Now, the form designer shows a blank form, and all those shiny components have all been erased from both the designer and the auto-generated code. Which, in such a simple program, is about 80% of the work I put into it.

Now, in NetBeans, I would right-click the file's tab, and just go back to a previous version, maybe losing about 15 minutes of work. This is a pretty obvious concept, I'm just not sure where to find file history in Visual Studio. So, where is the equivalent so I can get my work back?

(I've also managed to get my *code* back by just undoing a whole bunch - but the designer doesn't see it, and neither does the compiler, so it still builds to a blank form.)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you've just learned a couple of things.

One is to never, ever modify designer-generated code.  In fact, C# has a concept called [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which allow you to modify a generated class without having to modify the generated file.

Second, that Visual Studio in and of itself has no built in source code control -- you need to choose the one you like and be diligent in using it.  Some of the most popular are git, subversion, mercurial, and Team Foundation Server.  I personally use svn, but the others are good too.  Avoid something called Visual SourceSafe (VSS).

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of it, I'd say you tried ctrl-z until some point in your code, but not in the designer?
Performing multiple "undo's" in the code-behind file where you put your code is one thing, performing "undo's" in the designer is another.
Hopefully, you have not closed visual studio yet, and viewing your now blank form in design view, and trying a bunch of ctrl-z presses there, might do the trick.

Comment: No such luck. But I have been able to modify that code in the past, and have the changes propagate to the designer - any reason why it's not working now?

Comment: all designer code is kept in a seperate file, soemthing like: Form.Designer.cs. Whereas the code you write goes in Form.cs. The only reason I can think of is if you changed it, or did a combination of undo/re-do which caused the in-memory changes to be discarded...if what I suggested does not work, it seems you are out of luck this time :-( A hard lesson to learn, but I have learned it a few times myself. No auto-save-like-feature means beware what you do, and never mess in the designer.cs file, unless you really know what everything in there does and how it interacts with everything else.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I recovered the pieces that described the components, but I was apparently still missing the `this.Add()` lines that put everything on the form, which I had to re-add manually. A lot of work, but I guess I got lucky - this time.

Comment: welcome to the land of understanding what all that gobbley-gook in the designer.cs page is about :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Actually the controls are not lost from Design code or  Initialize
>   Component() ,make sure that whether check
>
> Initialize Component()  { this.controls.add("Where the control was ")
>   }
>
> Example:
>       1-this.Controls.Add(this.panel1.label1);    2-this.Controls.Add(this.panel1.label2);
>
> either in form you can write like below
>
> should write in the Initialize Component()

```
 this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar effect: the code wasn't lost because the project compiled perfectly but I only got a blank form in designer.

This was because the form was inherited from another form, and I added in the Load event of the base form the line: this.MdiParent = Application.OpenForms("BaseForm");

After deleting this line (and recompiling) I could access the design of the descendig forms again.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, it won't help you this time, but may be a good idea for the future - if you copy your code alot (like I do), get one of those clipboard savers - like [ClipTrap](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/fp/?page=cliptrap) (which is lightweight, simple, and great).

Then, if you realize you can't undo what you did, then you get a second chance by running through the "trapped" text to see if what you want might just be there.

Another good option is to try something like [AutoVer](http://beanland.net.au/AutoVer/), which will save a copy of any changed file (or files in a folder) every so often as you like.  This could provide you with a backup of your codefile, or even the entire project - every five minutes, or every minute as long as something has been changed.  Awesome program.  This is a certain fashion of source control, or at least source backup.

*(And no I'm not the authour of either application)*

However, for your particular problem, if the code is still there in your designer.cs page - maybe you just erased a reference or a namespace. Make sure the namespace matches, and make sure your in your form's code file, that the `InitializeComponent();` function is being called (that's what places all the designer's controls onto the form, you know).

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind file click 'undo', not in the designer window. Accept the warning, and when the code comes back, the form should be back to normal, Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by viewing my older commit and reverting the changes to that file. If I didn't have that I could make everything again from scratch.